# Word for the practical portion of my Ph.D?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Is there a (reasonably common) verb I can use meaning "to perform the practical work" of one’s PhD thesis that I can use to put in the following blank:

I have ____ my Ph.D. in the laboratory of Professor M. Hatter.

I can’t use "completed" because I’m lacking my defence as of I-don’t-yet-know-when-exactly.

Comment: If it's a Ph.D by research, you can say that you've finished *writing up*. If you want to talk about your association with the lab, you can say that your Ph.D *candidature* was conducted there.

Answer (score 4):

The academy uses the word *practicum* to describe the supervised application of a student's research and study of theory. Michigan State University describes the [practicum](http://education.msu.edu/kin/documents/bylaws/phdrespracticum.pdf) for a PhD in kinesiology thusly:

> The purpose of the research **practicum** in the Department of Kinesiology is to provide students with an
>   opportunity to learn and practice research skills early in the doctoral program of study. This research
>   **practicum** also provides the student’s guidance committee with an opportunity to assess the student’s
>   research knowledge and skills, with a goal of using the results to guide research mentoring efforts during the remainder of the degree program.

The requirement is that the "research **practicum** must be completed within the first two years or 36 credits of doctoral study, whichever occurs later." Thus you may use *complete* to describe your fulfillment of this PhD practicum before you complete the degree.

It would be wise to consult your own institution to find out whether they use this terminology.

Comment: +1  Nice. I did not know this word.

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

> I have *conducted my doctoral research* in the laboratory of Professor M. Hatter.

If the surrounding context makes it clear that you are discussing your Ph.D., you can leave out *doctoral*.

A quick web search for "conducting doctoral research" turns up several examples:

> - Conducting doctoral research requires the student to state the purpose of the study. ([refractivethinker.com](http://refractivethinker.com/articles/doctoral-research-the-importance-of-purpose/))
> - Conducting research / Conducting primary research (section headers on a [Purdue Online Writing Lab](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/section/2/8/) page)
> - This guide addresses the task of planning and conducting a small research project. ([University of Leicester](https://www2.le.ac.uk/offices/ld/resources/writing/writing-resources/planning-dissertation))